# Check 'nextTo' regions in Java

Tags: java

'NextTo' signifies which regions.
Stuck on parsing.

Comment: Just a little hint for the last section of your code. You don't have to check if it is true or false, just return the value of the comparison, it would look like this: `return (nextTo[region1] == region2);` This return statement either returns true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your pseudo-code is the right way to go.
Start by deserializing your JSON string with Jackson (find the appropriate "model", e.g. `nextTo` can be mapped to a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`) then implement your pseudo-code.

Comment: Thanks for help, could you show me an example, i'm very new to this language

Answer (score 0):

Deserialise object using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json),

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;



public class DesrialiseJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //json string
        String stringToParse="{\"Regions\" : [{\"regionId\" : 5,\"name\" : \"South Korea\"},{\"regionId\" : 6,\"name\" : \"North Korea\"},{ }],\"nextTo\" : { \"5\" : [6], \"6\" : [5]}}";
        try {
            //convert to json object
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
            System.out.println(checkNextTo(json));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkNextTo(JSONObject json) {
        //regions array
        JSONArray regionArr=(JSONArray) json.get("Regions");

        // Find the id of region1 in the "region" part of the JSON
        long regionId1=(Long) ((JSONObject) regionArr.get(0)).get("regionId");
        // Find the id of region2 in the "region" part of the JSON
        long regionId2=(Long) ((JSONObject) regionArr.get(1)).get("regionId");

        JSONObject nextTo=(JSONObject) json.get("nextTo");

        Long nextToReg1=(Long) ((JSONArray) nextTo.get(String.valueOf(regionId1))).get(0);
        Long nextToReg2=(Long) ((JSONArray) nextTo.get(String.valueOf(regionId2))).get(0);

        // Check region1's nextTo regions in the "nextTo" section ofJSON
        // If region2 id is in region1 id's nextTo {
        //return True 
        // Else

        return regionId1==nextToReg2 || regionId2==nextToReg1;


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, json file is already imported, so don't need to parse to string, how can I use your example, refering to json file

Comment: I just parsed so that I can get `JSONObject`. If you already have it then call `checkNextTo(json)` method.

Comment: works, but regionArr.get(0)).get("id") will only work for 1-5 integers,

Comment: @MikeM why  1-5 ? I have no where hard coded these values. It should have been a accepted answer.